# 1950s Era primary and secondary low voltage intercom system

Tags: transformer, relay, low-voltage

I have a 1959 low voltage panel right next to my 120 volt panel in my laundry room.
This panel controlled an Old intercom system as well as the lights for the house.
Inside of the panel there seems to be a number of rectifiers or relays, I'm not 100% sure how to tell. I've never seen a panel like this before because it appears that all the commons and all the grounds for both panels are Daisy chained together.

I've lost power to half of my light fixtures, as well as multiple fixtures turning on and off, or flickering constantly.

I am planning on replacing the transformer in the secondary box with a 20V>1A dc supply.

My question is about a relay next to the transformer. I have shut off power to the relay at the fuse panel on the primary box hours ago, but the relay remains hot to the touch.

The relay is a BT 58 Class II
115V 60C .30A 3v DC

What could be the cause of this, and would it be smarter to use a higher voltage power supply?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to EE! I was reviewing your question, but there are some things I'm not sure how to interpret, like "secondary box with a *20V>1A* dc supply" - would that be less that 20 V, or more than 1 A? Also *.30A* is 0.3 or another value?

Comment: It's a bit tricky to understand what is going on. Can you provide some photos of both panels that really show what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a low voltage system you should have a box full of relays. The relay contacts control your 120 V lights. The relay coils are energized by a low voltage. So your light switches will switch the low voltage to energize a relay coil and the relay will then switch 120 V to whichever lights are connected to it.

If you have shut off power to a relay at the 120 V fuse panel it could still have it's coil energized by the low voltage, and that could cause it to feel hot.

As for using a higher voltage supply, that would not be wise. The relay coils are designed to work at a certain voltage, increasing the voltage will likely cause them to overheat. From the relay description they appear to be 3 V relays, so going to 20 V is not going to be good, I'd expect smoke and destroyed relays.

Keep in mind that the relays will have 120 V on them, so while it's called a low voltages system it can still kill you. You may want to consult a qualified electrician, and since for some reason you've decided to just throw a random power supply in there I'm going to say it's not even *may* want to, it's *will* want to.